# Codeigniter: Categories and Subcategories

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

I am trying to make **Categories** and **Subcategories** for a restaurant menu.

The **subcategories** have additional fields like `price`, `description` and **categories** only have `id` and `name`. So I decided to go with those two tables.

```
Categories    -> ID, NAME
Subcategoires -> ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION, PRICE, CATEGORIES_ID,
```

Now I am trying to structure them to make a nice looking menu.

I am also using DataMapper for Codeigniter.

So far I have this:

```
$categories = new Category_model();
$subcategories = new Subcategory_model();
$categories->get();
$subcategories->get();

$recent_categories = array();
$recent_subcategories = array();

foreach ($categories as $category)
{
    $single_category = array
    (
        'category_id' => $category->id,
        'category_name' => $category->name,
    );

    foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory)
    {
        if ($subcategory->categories_id == $category->id)
        {
            $single_subcategory = array
            (
                'subcategory_id' => $subcategory->id,
                'subcategory_name' => $subcategory->name,
                'subcategory_description' => $subcategory->description,
                'subcategory_price' => $subcategory->price,
            );
        }
    }

    array_push($recent_categories, $single_category);
    array_push($recent_subcategories, $single_subcategory);
}
```

It's almost working by one little problem it is printing both `SUBCATEGORIES` for both `CATEGORIES`. Where it needs to be only one for each.

So now is looking like this:

```
ALCOHOL
    - VODKA
    - COLA
NON-ALCOHOL
    - VODKA
    - COLA
```

and obviously I want it to be `VODKA` for `ALCOHOL` and `COLA` for `NON-ALCOHOL`.

Can someone please point me how to make it work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should just populate the array immediately.

Assuming your content looks like this..

```
    $categories = array("alcohol", "non-alcohol");
    $subcategories = array(
                     (object)array("category" => "alcohol", "name" => "vodka"),
                     (object)array("category" => "non-alcohol", "name" => "cola")
                   );

    foreach ($categories as $category)
    {
        $recent_categories[] = $category;

        foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory => $subcat)
        {               
            $recent_subcategories[$subcat->name][] = $subcat->name;
        }
    }
```

This will result:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "alcohol"
  [1]=>
  string(11) "non-alcohol"
}

array(2) {
  ["alcohol"]=>
  string(5) "vodka"
  ["non-alcohol"]=>
  string(4) "cola"
}
```

Comment: This will override the last product name of same category if there is more than one product of that category

Comment: Yeah I see but I want the informaton to be in the database, not hard coded

Answer (score 0):

```
$categories = array("alcohol", "non-alcohol");
$subcategories = array(
                 (object)array("category" => "alcohol", "name" => "vodka"),
                 (object)array("category" => "non-alcohol", "name" => "cola")
               );
$recent_subcategories = array();
foreach ($categories as $category)
{
    $recent_categories[] = $category;

    foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory => $subcat)
    {               
        $recent_subcategories[$subcat->name][] = $subcat->name;
    }
}
```

The Out put of that is

array(
'Categories' => array(Subcategories)
)